# ¿Por qué me recarga la página el AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

estoy haciendo unas pruebas, y con un botón activo un `AJAX`, pero este me recarga la página, no sé que tengo mal.

Este es mi código:

```
$(function(){
      $("#pruebaMia").click(function(e){
        var contenido = "";
        var contenido2 = "";
         $.ajax({
             url: "editar_ot.php",
             type: "post",
             dataType: "html",
             data: {
                'contenido': $("#ContenedorElegido").html(),
                'contenido2': $("#generalElegido").html()
             },
             beforeSend: function(){
               $("#mensaje").html("Procesando, espere por favor...")
             },
             success: function (res){
               $("#mensaje").html(res);
             }
         });
     });
  });
```

**En editar_ot.php**

```
<?php
    echo $contenido=$_POST['contenido'];
    echo $contenido2=$_POST['contenido2'];
 ?>

 <div class="">
   Esto es una prueba
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que es porque no has previsto el default, intenta asi:

```
$(function(){
      $("#pruebaMia").click(function(e){

        event.preventDefault(); // Añade esto para prevenir el default

        var contenido = "";
        var contenido2 = "";
         $.ajax({
             url: "editar_ot.php",
             type: "post",
             dataType: "html",
             data: {
                'contenido': $("#ContenedorElegido").html(),
                'contenido2': $("#generalElegido").html()
             },
             beforeSend: function(){
               $("#mensaje").html("Procesando, espere por favor...")
             },
             success: function (res){
               $("#mensaje").html(res);
             }
         });
     });
  });
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta tan rápida, y para que sirve eso de `event.preventDefault();` @Josue Arriola

Comment: Prevent default es un metodo que tienen los eventos que permite hacer que el comportamiento por defecto de lo que sea que haga el evento no sea ejecutado,  es decir,  si por ejemplo tu evento es de tipo click sera ejecutado,  pero aquellas cosas que desencadene el evento no lo haran, por ejemplo si al momento de darle click a un boton el boton es de tipo submit, puedes hacer que el comportamiento por defecto de este boton (recargar la pagina) ya no lo haga con preventDefault.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración!

Answer (score 0):

al a;adir event.preventDefault(); solo haces que el codigo se detenga hasta esa posicion es practicamente lo mismo que un die();

una pregunta aca

```
  data: {
            'contenido': $("#ContenedorElegido").html(),
            'contenido2': $("#generalElegido").html()
         },
```

por que tienes contenido  y contenido2 entre comillas simples si mal no recuerdo la sintaxis de ajax no requiere eso prueba quitandolos

Comment: El boton que usas tiene algun type="submit" o algo parecido?

Comment: AJAX creo que seria mejor quitarles las comillas donde dice contenido y contenido 2

y seria merjor declarar variables con ese jquery  y llamarla como el valor de cada contenido

Comment: Diculpa mi ignoracion soy nuevo en esto pero el que eh llegado a usar no uso comillas simples

Comment: Gracias por tus respuestas! arriba tienes la respuesta correcta para la solución! gracias y bienvenido!